# method of one task is automatically called by another task in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, console, user-input, build.gradle

I am facing the problem in *build.gradle* file. I am using gradle version **2.14.1**. In my gradle build there is a function named `ask()`,I am using in `task grun(type:JavaExec) {...}`, which is automatically called by other tasks. I don't want this to happen. `ask()` function invokes gradle console to get input from user while I run `gradle grun --no-daemon`. But I am getting console in all gradle tasks like `gradle compile --no-daemon` , `gradle grunGui --no-daemon` or `gradle grunTree --no-daemon` and no other task is depended on this task except `grun`. This is my gradle code:

```
apply plugin: 'antlr'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  antlr 'org.antlr:antlr4:4.5.2'    // using ANTLR v4
}

generateGrammarSource {
  /*arguments += ["-visitor", "-long-messages"]*/
  arguments += ["-visitor", "-no-listener"]
}

task compile(type: JavaCompile){
  classpath = project.getConfigurations().getByName(AntlrPlugin.ANTLR_CONFIGURATION_NAME) + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  source = fileTree(dir: 'src/main/', include: '*.java')
  destinationDir = file('build/classes/main')
}

task grunGui (type:JavaExec){
  classpath = project.getConfigurations().getByName(AntlrPlugin.ANTLR_CONFIGURATION_NAME) + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'

  def grammarName = "Wolf"
  args = [grammarName, 'init', '-gui', "src/main/Wolf/first.wlf"]
}

task grunTokens (type:JavaExec){
  classpath = project.getConfigurations().getByName(AntlrPlugin.ANTLR_CONFIGURATION_NAME) + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'

  def grammarName = "Wolf"
  args = [grammarName, 'init', '-tokens', "src/main/Wolf/first.wlf"]
}

task grunTree (type:JavaExec){
  classpath = project.getConfigurations().getByName(AntlrPlugin.ANTLR_CONFIGURATION_NAME) + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'

  def grammarName = "Wolf"
  args = [grammarName, 'init', '-tree', "src/main/Wolf/first.wlf"]
}

def ask() {
  def console = System.console()
  if (console)
    return console.readLine('\n> Please enter input string or filename to parse OR press enter⏎ to skip:\n')
  else
    logger.error "Cannot get console. Using default inputFile src/main/Wolf/first.wlf"
  return ''
}

task grun(type:JavaExec) {
  classpath = project.getConfigurations().getByName(AntlrPlugin.ANTLR_CONFIGURATION_NAME) + sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
  main = 'Wolf'
  def input = ask()
  args = input.length() > 0 ? [input] : ["src/main/Wolf/first.wlf"]
}
```

[Console is coming while calling compile task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2SCk.png)

Comment: Do you want `ask()` run only with `grun` task?

Comment: Yes, I want ask() should run with `grun` task only..

Comment: for me your config looks sane and it should work like you expect. So I suggest you debug you build process to find out what is cause of `ask` invocation. Info about gradle debug:  http://georgik.sinusgear.com/2014/06/23/how-to-debug-gradle-script/

Comment: I am wondering without calling ask in any other task except `grun` , why console is coming to other gradle tasks.